# Python3 Threading: Why are 2 threads active when I have only started one?

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy

Can someone explain to me, why there are 2 threads (Thread-1 & Thread-2) active
when I have only set one thread : (my_thread)?
Thread-1 appears to be True all the time and never becomes False.
How do I correct my code so that only one thread is active and becomes False
when the 'Stop' Button is pressed.
This is the first program I've written using Threading and I'm at a loss
to understand it.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from time import sleep
import threading


class MyApp(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'horizontal'
        self.running=False
        
        self.btn = Button(text='Start', size_hint_x=.1)        
        self.lbl = Label(size_hint_x=.9)
        
        self.add_widget(self.btn)
        self.btn.bind(on_press = self.start_stop)
        self.add_widget(self.lbl)

    def do_something(self,n):
        while self.running:
            self.lbl.text = str(n)
            sleep(.5)
            n += 1
        else:
            self.show_running_threads()
                
    def start_stop(self,event):
        if self.running:
            self.btn.text = 'Start'
        else:
            self.btn.text = 'Stop'
            self.running = False            

        self.running = not self.running 
        self.my_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.do_something,args = (0,))
        self.my_thread.start()

    def show_running_threads(self):
        runningThreads = []
        for thread in threading.enumerate():
            runningThreads.append(thread.name)
            self.lbl.text = 'Running threads: ' + str(runningThreads) +\
                            '\n my_thread running = ' + str(self.my_thread.is_alive())
            
        print(runningThreads)
        
        if self.my_thread.is_alive():
            print('my_thread still running')
        else:
            print('my_thread cancelled\n','-'*80,sep='')
        
class MyLayout(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyApp()
      
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyLayout().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems here. To answer your immediate question, the reason why you're ending up with two threads is because `start_stop()` creates a new thread regardless of which action is requested. Here is an alternative, with some logic simplified:

```
    def do_something(self,n):
        while self.running:
            self.lbl.text = str(n)
            sleep(.5)
            n += 1

    def start_stop(self,event):
        if not self.running:
            self.running = True
            self.btn.text = 'Stop'
            self.my_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.do_something,args = (0,))
            self.my_thread.start()
        else:
            self.running = False
            self.my_thread.join()
            self.my_thread = None
            self.btn.text = 'Start'
            self.show_running_threads()
```

It's a good idea to call `join()` to wait for the exiting thread, so you can display the correct status and not worry about whether the thread has actually completed its `while` loop and exited.

A related problem is that you were calling `show_running_threads()` from inside the thread, so it's never going to report that the thread has been cancelled because the thread is still alive at that moment. I moved that to the stop action in `start_stop`.

I wasn't sure if most of the logic in `show_running_threads()` was just for debugging, so I didn't revise that, but you may at least want to change:

```
if self.my_thread.is_alive():
```

to:

```
if self.my_thread and self.my_thread.is_alive():
```

as the change to `start_stop()` sets `self.my_thread` to `None` when the previous thread ends. You may also want to adjust the `print()` in `show_running_threads()` so it prints `False` when `self.my_thread` is `None`.

Comment: show_running_threads, was as you suspected, just for debegging. I've made the changes you suggested.  A little more effort on my part to understand  join() and setting the variable to None. It says I shouldn't but thank you.